# Image not visible when viewing from the Community View

Tags: static-resources, customer-community

I have uploaded the image into the static resource and refer the image to some formula field. Its working fine. But when I am shifting the view form admin view to customer-community view the image not visible.

I think permission issue. but I don't know how to resolve that.

**My Formula code :**

```
CASE(   action , "smily", IMAGE("/resource/1395482876000/Images/123.png","smily",20,20))
```

**Community Customer View:**

[image]

**My Admin View:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following code in your formula field.

```
IMAGE(LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))++"resource/. imgae
```

Comment: Nice one. SFDC should definitely make this simpler and more generic, by just enabling $resource.imagename in formula fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an absolute path to your static resource.

```
https://emea.salesforce.com/resource/1399493228000/SiteSamples -> /resource/1399493228000/SiteSamples
```

Comment: Yes. I have set that also.

Comment: Are you using a formula to get the url of your static resource?

Comment: Yes. the problem is when I am switch the view to community customer view, the image not visible.

Comment: I have updated the image FYI.

Comment: can you please share your formula? (Maybe you are using an absolute paths to your image.)

Comment: Updated the image

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: If I give along with base URL its work so how to append the base url in formula field

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the resource's Cache Control is set to Public (https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_resources_create.htm).