# Broken image appears for maintainence page of community

Tags: community, customer-community, static-resources

Hii I have created a community in my sandbox org and then I deployed it in the production org.

I have created a maintainence page where I used an image as a static resource.I have given public access to it.When I am logged in to my salesforce org the image is perfect .

But when my community is not Active this maintainence page appears but I get to see a broken image 
[image]

How do I correct this problem.Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to use the public URL of the image. You can store the image in documents, from there make it public, and right click on image and get the public URL.

Then use that public URL, please follow the below screenshot. [image]

Comment: Actually the whole website we have created with the help of static resources only. The exception is showing for this page only .All the other images for other pages are showing fine

Comment: are all other static resources image only? Can you please share the line you have written to use this image on this page.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193729&type=1

Comment: possible duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37268/image-not-visible-when-viewing-from-the-community-view

Comment: <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Logistic_img_new, 'img/logo.png')}" class="main-logo" alt=""/>   I have  written this line to use this image on this page

Comment: Please check the links I have shared.

Comment: Saswata, if it helped please upvote and mark the answer as best.